# QT thread never runs

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm trying to use a Qthread but can't seem to figure out when the thread actually executes.  I've only been able to see it's execution when the function creating the thread exits but I don't want my current function to exit after a single execution.  I'd like to run the thread many times in a loop within this function.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
// --- PROCESS ---
// Start processing data.
void GrayDisplay::process() 
{
    std::cout << "Thread context!" << std::endl;  //I never see this print

    emit finished();
}


void gig::OnPlay()
{
    //Create thread and assign selected
    QThread* thread = new QThread;

    if(ui->colorBox->currentIndex() == 0 )
    {
        GrayDisplay* display = new GrayDisplay();
        display->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(display, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), display, SLOT(process()));
        connect(display, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
        connect(display, SIGNAL(finished()), display, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

        std::cout << "Creating Thread!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid mode selected";
        return;
    }

    pSemaphore->acquire();
    run = true;
    pSemaphore->release();

    //Read data
    while(run)  //set false by click event
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        Sleep(33);
        if (thread->isRunning())  //Always prints and I expect just the first loop iteration to print, not infinitely as it does
            cout << "Worker is-STILL-Running\n";

        thread->start();
        QApplication::exec();
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
//      while (!thread->isFinished())
//      {
//          QApplication::exec();
//          QCoreApplication::processEvents();
//      }   //Never returns
    }   //WHILE RUN LOOP

    return;
}
```

I've seen similar threads on here but the solution always seems to be:
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
This doesn't seem to help me.  If I create and start the thread it always seems to be running but never does anything(never see my print statement) and never finishes.  I added the sleep to simulate the time each loop will take for each loop to finish before it needs to start a new thread.  I expect the previous thread to have finished by that time.  I'm trying to get a simple version working properly but can't figure out what I'm missing.  I only want to delete the thread when I leave the OnPlay() function but execute the thread many times until I decide to exit.

Comment: Why do you have `QApplication::exec();` in there?

Comment: There is no loop because QApplication::exec(); never finishes.

Comment: Just something someone suggested on one of the many forums I searched so I thought I'd try it.  It looks like that may have been the problem.  I just started trying anything after a while and that appears to have been a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I was mistaken that wasn't the issue.  I still see the thread running forever but never actually doing anything or finishing.  I had tried calling the display->process() explicitly and forgot to remove it when I removed QApplication::exec();  My thread is still useless when I try using thread->start.  Only calling process explicitly seems to work but that isn't really a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same issue as I in the following thread: [Why do my threads not exit gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632868/why-do-my-threads-not-exit-gracefully).

The problem is that the event loop of your thread is only established **after** process() returns. This means that all quit events which where sent to your thread before this time will be deleted.

qeventloop.cpp:

```
// remove posted quit events when entering a new event loop
QCoreApplication *app = QCoreApplication::instance();
if (app && app->thread() == thread())
    QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents(app, QEvent::Quit);
```

In my case, a simple

```
QThread::currentThread()->quit();
```

at the end of process() did the trick.