# Why do my threads not exit gracefully?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I try to tell a thread to quit gracefully. For this purpose, the thread checks in every iteration a global boolean flag, which indicates if the thread should continue or exit. The thread is setup like this (code is from http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/):

```
ImageFusionQt::ImageFusionQt(QWidget* parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{    

captureThread = new QThread();
captureWorker = new CaptureWorker();

// Connects the threads started() signal to the process() slot in the worker, causing it to start.
connect(captureThread, SIGNAL(started()), captureWorker, SLOT(process()));

// Connect worker finished signal to trigger thread quit, then delete.
connect(captureWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), captureThread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(captureWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), captureWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// Make sure the thread object is deleted after execution has finished.
connect(captureThread, SIGNAL(finished()), captureThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// Give QThread ownership of Worker Object
captureWorker->moveToThread(captureThread);
captureThread->start();

}
```

CaptureWorker.cpp

```
void CaptureWorker::process()
{
  while(true)
  {
    g_exit_lock->lockForRead();
    if( g_exit )
    {
      g_exit_lock->unlock();
      break;
    }
    g_exit_lock->unlock();
  }
  qDebug() << "CaptureWorker: Exiting.";
  emit finished();
 }
```

Now, when I try to stop the thread by setting the flag to true in some function, the process() method returns but the thread does not finish and the call to wait() blocks forever. Why does my thread not terminate?

```
g_exit_lock->lockForWrite();
g_exit = true;
g_exit_lock->unlock();

QThread::sleep(15);
qDebug() << "ct finished? " << captureThread->isFinished();

captureThread->wait();
qDebug() << "All threads stopped.";
```

Logfile output:

```
2013.03.26 09:29:22[D] CaptureWorker: Exiting. 
2013.03.26 09:29:37[D] ct finished?  false
```

**UPDATE**

I did some debugging and found out some intersting stuff:

- The thread blocks in its event loop (QEventLoop::exec). It waits for a quit() signal it apparently does not receive.
- The event loop of the thread is created **after** process() returns. By hooking up the signals as I did, the run() method of the thread is called after the thread has already finished doing its work (e.g. process() returned).
- The event loop clears all posted quit events before doing the actual loop.

**My conclusion**

- Connecting the quit() slot as I did does not work because quit() events are deleted when the event loop is established
- Calling the quit() member function directly on the thread object, does apparently lead to a graceful termination. This can be done from outside or from inside by using QThread::currentThread()->quit();

**Open Questions**

- Is there a way to call the process() method after the event loop has been established?
- It feels wrong that the event loop is created when the work is allready done. However, the way I use QThread is in line with the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details)

Comment: Perhaps you just need to flush the debug stream?

Comment: what is the content of finished() ?

Comment: Logging is a *very* unproductive way to debug programs.  Learn how to use a debugger instead.  Just attach the debugger, break the program, switch the context to the worker thread and find out what it is doing from the stack trace.  With high odds that you'll now discover that it isn't executing the loop but is buried in some kind of OS call, waiting for the capture to complete.  So it isn't testing g_exit so it isn't quitting.

Comment: @Nick: Valid remark, however I just put a break point befor and after wait() and it did indeed block.

Comment: @faith_k: It's a Qt-Signal. I dont think I am supposed to implment it.

Comment: Then what is the related slot for finished()?

Comment: @fatih_k: I think its stated in the question, isn't it? The worker's finished() signal is connected to QObject::deleteLater and QThread::quit

Comment: deleteLater may be the problem

Comment: Updated my question and found a solution. It still feels hacky, though.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is `quit` not being called at all.
You know Qt has direct or queued connection. When you use this

```
connect(captureWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), captureThread, SLOT(quit()));
```

it's really an auto connection type. So because you moved captureWorker to another thread,  [Qt::QueuedConnecton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) is used. The `quit()` will be called on the **main** thread. But what you do is block the main thread with `captureThread->wait();`
`quit()` is queued in the event loop, but it is blocked because it's waiting for the thread to finish.
So you might want to call quit() directly like by replacing

```
connect(captureWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), captureThread, SLOT(quit()));
```

with

```
connect(captureWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), captureThread, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Or call quit() directly like you suggested in the edits, or you can also do something like the following instead of `captureThread->wait();` if you really need to

```
  QEventLoop l;
  l.connect(captureThread, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));  
  l.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
```

Alternatively you can connect to thread's finished() signal and do whatever you wanted to do after `captureThread->wait();` so you don't have to wait manually at all.
There are many ways of doing things in Qt

Comment: Thanks for your input. Btw, I updated my question while you gave this answer. I struggle to understand your answer: I know that captureThread lives in the main thread, but calling its quit() slot should nevertheless quit the thread it is managing, no? And I dont get in which way your suggestion is better than just doing captureThread->quit(). Can you expand on that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, calling quit() will stop the event loop. The matter is where it's being called. Since captureThread lives in the main thread, you should call it's methods in the main thread because Qt classes are reentrant.

Comment: By the way i don't think that it's possible that event loop of the thread is created after process() returns. Maybe you've mixed up the main thread's event loop and the worker's thread event loop

Comment: Ok. I dont understand your statement fully because I haven't put a lot of effort in thinking about it ;), but in essence you say calling QThread::currentThread()->quit() from the capture thread is bad bad bad. Right?

Comment: actually i think i was wrong. Though i couldn't find it in the docs, exit() method has a mutex so calling quit() or exit() should be fine.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I checked the sources and QThread::quit() is indeed mutexed.

Comment: If CaptureWorker::process() blocks the secondary thread's event loop, the event loop won't be quit.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the event loop does not even exist when process() is called, therefore there is nothing to be blocked. But I guess you are right that process() would block the event loop (if it existed).

Comment: If CaptureWorker::process() blocks the secondary thread's event loop (which it looks like), the event loop won't be quit. Instead of calling quit(), the main thread should set some "quit" flag in the secondary thread (protected by mutex/qatomic) and process() should check that as it does with g_exit.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Frank, the event loop is established in QThread::exec, but process() runs before that. I double-checked this in the Qt source and debugged it through. So, there is no event loop to block. The quit() gets eaten up by QCoreApplication::removePostedEvents(app, QEvent::Quit); which is called when the event loop is created.

Comment: @binford i still think you've mixed up the main thread event loop and the worker thread event loop. The process() can't run before worker thread event loop is created  
@FrankOsterfeld there is a quit flag in `process()` method

Comment: @10WaRRioR01: Im still inclined to disagree. 1. The worker thread event loop is created in QThread::exec(qthread.cpp, l.519) which is called by QThread::run. 2. The "started" signal to which I connect the process() slot, **is emitted before QThread::run** (qthread_win.cpp, l. 339). IMHO, while process() is running, there is no event loop.

Comment: @binford: Your observation is correct. `started` is emitted before the event loop starts. Then, e.g. `deleteLater` doesn't behave as expected. Try connecting to `started` via `Qt::QueuedConnection`, then your `process()` slot should be called with the event loop running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are actually blocking the main thread and event loop, so as result not letting the thread to receive quit signal.
The problem will be fixed by doing as follow:

```
g_exit_lock->lockForWrite();
g_exit = true;
g_exit_lock->unlock();

QThread::sleep(15);
qDebug() << "ct finished? " << captureThread->isFinished();

// You are missing below line, without this, main thread will block
captureThread->quit();
captureThread->wait();

qDebug() << "All threads stopped.";
```